# How to show Nextcloud calendars in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I am the admin of a Nextcloud instance v26.0.2, hosting a number of calendars. I can import all of them in one go into Thunderbird, using an URL like https://nextcloud.example.com/remote.php/dav

However, my users want to see their **private** Nextcloud calendars in the Google calendar webinterface.

I tried Add calendar » From URL, but it doesn’t ask for username and password, like Thunderbird does:
[image]

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

In Nextcloud, there are two types of calendar links. The one you described are internal links, which Gcal does not support since it doesn't let you put in your credentials.

There is also the "Share link" which creates a secret url to a public copy of your calendar. However, note that this cal will be read-only.

[image: share link in nextcloud]